# In certain proof: Using properties of the integral

Tags: integration

I would like to know which theorem was used in the following two inequalities.

If $f>0$ on [a,b], $p\geq1$, $q>0$, then

$$\int_{a}^{b} f^{p}(t) \int_{t}^{b} x^{-p} (x-a)^{p-1} dx dt \leq \int_{a}^{b} f^{p}(t) \: t^{-p} \int_{t}^{b} (x-a)^{p-1} dx dt$$

Also,

$$\int_{a}^{b} f^{p}(t) \int_{t}^{b} x^{-p} (x-a)^{p-1} dx dt \geq \int_{a}^{b} f^{p}(t) \: b^{-p} \int_{t}^{b} (x-a)^{p-1} dx dt$$

[The 1st inequality is more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dJTu.jpg) ,

[The 2nd inequality is more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lQE9.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: If $t\le x\le b$ then $x^{-p}\le t^{-p}$ and $x^{-p}\ge b^{-p}.$ This is for $p>0$ (there is no $q$) and $b\ge a\ge0.$